# How can I use the Google Translate API inside a redux async thunk?

Tags: javascript, npm, google-cloud-platform, google-translate, google-translation-api

I have been trying to integrate the google translate API with my redux app, but I can't seem to get it to work. I have downloaded my private keys and saved them to a local file path. When I run the [example code](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-translate/blob/master/samples/translate.js) it work perfectly. The problem arises when I try to call the `translate` function inside my async redux thunk, as follows:

```
const projectId = '{my google cloud project id goes here}'
const keyFilename = '{the full path to my private key goes here}'
const translate = new Translate({projectId, keyFilename});

export const addPairs = createAsyncThunk(
    'pairs/addPairs',
    async () => {
        let [translations] = await translate.translate('hello world', 'en');
        return translations
    }
)
```

Whenever I call this function using `dispatch`, it always returns this error:

```
fs.createReadStream is not a function
```

I can't seem to figure out why this is the case and I have already tried to search up for any other solutions but it doesn't seem that anyone has had a similar use case before... Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that I couldn't read the key from my local filesystem on the browser (as the API was obviously intended for server-side code) so the best way to go would be to set up a local server to serve the API and then access that from the client. Oops.